# Adding VM's to Domain

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, sharepoint, farm

I am trying to configure SP farm, in Azure, following steps mention in this article - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt723354(v=office.16).aspx 
But after creating Sql VM('sqlVM' ), I am not able to add this to the AD domain.

Below error message is displayed while trying to connect to Domain.

> PS C:\Users\anuvya> Add-Computer -DomainName "corp.contoso.com"
>
> cmdlet Add-Computer at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for
>   the following parameters: Add-Computer : Computer 'sqlVM' failed to
>   join domain 'corp.contoso.com' from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP'
>   with  following error message: The specified domain either does not
>   exist or could not be contacted. At line:1 char:1
>   + Add-Computer -DomainName "corp.contoso.com"
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (sqlVM:String) [Add-Computer], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToJoinDomainFromWorkgroup,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerComman

Any inputs will be appreciated.

Thanks,

====================

Answer (score 12):

Agree with @garbrad. According to the error message, the SQL VM can't locate the DC.

Please check the DNS settings on the SQL VM, if it is not the private IP address of your DC VM, then you need to check the DNS settings of VNET. VNET uses Azure provided name resolution as the default settings. To change it, please refer to the screenshot below:

[image]

If the DNS settings are correct, then you need to check if the [DNS records](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx) are created on the DC VM properly.

Also, here is a good article about [How Domain Controllers are Located in Windows](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24457.how-domain-controllers-are-located-in-windows.aspx), which is helpful for you to understand the whole process.

Answer (score 11):

Generally when domain join says "the domain doesn't exist or cannot be contacted" it's because the VM isn't configured to use the AD DC as its DNS server.  Check if the DNS server on the VNET matches the IP of the DC and that the VM is using that IP (ipconfig /all).  If the DNS server was set on the vnet after the VM was recreated then the vm either needs a reboot or an ipconfig /refresh

Answer (score 10):

You would need to have restart flag at the end.

Also this command uses the local user account to add to the domain.

```
Add-Computer -DomainName "corp.contoso.com" -restart
```

IF the local user account cannot add the PC to the domain you can use:

```
Add-Computer -ComputerName "Server01" -LocalCredential "Server01\Admin01" -DomainName "Domain02" -Credential Domain02\Admin02 -Restart -Force
```

It will prompt your for a password